# Mysql UPDATE Query error: Unknown Column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I am trying to add a new column by using the following query:

```
UPDATE t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
       t1.CID as t1_id,
       t2.id as t2_id
    FROM t3
    INNER JOIN t1 ON t3.CID = t1.CID
    INNER JOIN t4 ON t4.MID = t3.MID
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.serial = t4.Serial 
        AND t3.Time BETWEEN t2.Start_Time AND t2.End_Time) as sub
ON sub.t1_id = t1.CID
SET t1.t2_id = sub.t2_id
```

Shows the error: `Unknown column 't1.t2_ID' in 'field list'`

I have seen couple of `fieldlist` error solutions but none of them actually helped me. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do the columns exist in the table?

Comment: is the name exactly that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want add a column use `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD [COLUMN] column_name column_definition [FIRST|AFTER existing_column];
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/

Then you can use `UPDATE` to fill that field